# How detect statistically non-deterministic values from array of importance weight of instances?

Tags: matlab, statistics

Suppose I have an array A includes the importance weights of instances corresponding the index. I want to find the insignificant instances by using these importance metrics (it is something like feature selections. I want to eleminate insignificant one for better performance). I tried boxplot but is there any other methods works better theoretically for such purposes?

Comment: Can you explain it with some proper example?

Comment: I also would like to ask for an example. It is realy not clear. Are you are saying that you want to remove outliers?